# Display List of WPF Objects in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This is hard to explain, and I am still pretty novice so I am apologies in advance.

Is there a way to take a WPF XAML document and display a list of them in a listBox?

Like if I wanted to make a contact list. I could create a .xaml file with the stuff I want (Icon, String to hold name, icon to show cell/home/pager) then call in to a list as if it were  a class that I am making an instance off to fill the list.

Any help, even just a name, pattern or keyword to lookup, would be extremely helpful.

Thanks,
Dane

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you are looking for is called an `ItemTemplate`. It's a description of what each item in your collection should look like in your view.

A nice tutorial can be found [here](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-data-binding-item-template/).

Comment: Thank you very very much.  I have been googling around for "List objects" "List WPF files" "WPF Contact List" for hours.  This is exactly what I was looking for.